# How to pattern-match against an enum variant that wraps a String?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have an enum:

```
enum T {
    A(String),
}
```

I want to match a variable of this enum, but this code doesn't work:

```
match t {
    T::A("a") => println!("a"),
    T::A("b") => println!("b"),
    _ => println!("something else"),
}
```

I understand that I can do this, but it is so verbose in my opinion:

```
match t {
    T::A(value) => match value.as_ref() {
        "a" => println!("a"),
        "b" => println!("b"),
        _ => println!("something else"),
    },
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: You can also "transform" your problem by creating a parallel enum that has a `&str` instead of a `String`, but most people don't like that solution.

Answer (score 9):

The only other way I think would be to use a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards), but this is about as verbose as your version with nested matches.

```
match t {
    T::A(ref value) if value == "a" => println!("a"),
    T::A(ref value) if value == "b" => println!("b"),
    _ => println!("something else"),
}
```