# How to match against nested String in Rust

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

How do I match against a *nested* `String` in Rust? Suppose I have an enum like

```
pub enum TypeExpr {
    Ident((String, Span)),
    // other variants...
}
```

and a value `lhs` of type `&Box<TypeExpr>`. How do I check whether it is an `Ident` with the value "float"?

I tried

```
if let TypeExpr::Ident(("float", lhs_span)) = **lhs {}
```

but this doesn't work since `TypeExpr` contains a `String`, not a `&str`. I tried every variation of the pattern I could think of, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pattern-match against an enum variant that wraps a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075255/how-to-pattern-match-against-an-enum-variant-that-wraps-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with an `if let`, you might have to do it like this

```
if let TypeExpr::Ident((lhs_name, lhs_span)) = lhs {
    if lhs_name == "float" {
        // Do the things
    }
}
```

Of course, it can also be done with a `match`:

```
match lhs {
    TypeExpr::Ident((lhs_name, lhs_span)) if lhs_name == "float" => {
        // Do the things
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

Comment: The problem with the nested if version is that it means duplicating the else code. But the pattern match with guard approach looks like it might work. Thanks! I just wish there were a nicer way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that feeling. I had to do something similar to this in a project where I was generating an AST. In general, my pattern is to use enums as much as possible, and avoid Boxing them, to make pattern matching as seamless as I can make it. This is sometimes infeasible, so we do what we must. :)

Comment: The problem is that you need boxing with a recursive tree.

Comment: Yes, though there are nested matching techniques to work around that, it's just annoying if you like to pattern match.